# Workflow issue that has been completely baffling

Tags: 8, composer

One of my developers, who has been working with Drupal since he started several months ago, recently ran into an issue with the composer install command that failed with the following error:

> [image: screenshot]

After several days of troubleshooting, we still haven't overcome this issue on the laptop machine.

The thing is that his computer is the only one that exhibits this issue. The same commit on other computers (including one with the same OS and one with another) work perfectly, as they have done for months.

The developer is one of several who have worked on the site in the past. As with all our new sites, we include composer.lock files in our repositories. Older Drupal 8 sites, which started development without Composer at all, have since been updated to work with Composer.

The issue seemed to be on the computer in general, since other projects now result in the same error. After days of debugging and eventually trying XAMMP and MAMP (running into other issues, but still coming full circle) - we still had the same issue on this machine (all the while, the same repository working fine on other PCs).

So we wiped the computer and started from scratch (Macos Mojave), installed fresh MySql, PHP, Apache versions and still the same issue.

Like many other developers who made the transition 'off-the-island', I had difficulties with composer at the start, but I have since learned much, and improved the workflow in my team to avoid these issues.

This issue seems not resolvable by any of the conventional means: We've tried updating composer, we've tried clearing the composer cache, we've tried fixing the AMP stack versions to ensure that issues aren't from there.

Googling gives many *I don't get Composer, please help* links. I haven't come across anything like this anywhere.

We need help to get beyond this. Bearing in mind that two of my team of three can work fine, ti's just one developer who has this issue, and recently at that (so the workflows we have in place has worked fine for months and months, I can't envision that we need to make drastic changes to that).

I also understand that installing docker or some other VM like solution is designed to avoid such issues, but we're not ready to make that transition now for various reasons.

Comment: PS, the example console output above states v8.6.1, but I the same issue presents on 8.6.2 on the machine in question.

Comment: `composer why drupal/drupal` might shed some light. I know you'll tell me where to stick this, but It seems highly, _highly_ likely that the website files on the machine where it's not working are different to the ones on a machine where it is working, or at least that the versions of composer are drastically different between the two. There's an easy way to test. Make sure the composer versions are identical on one machine where it works and one where it doesn't, delete composer.lock on both, and run `composer install` on both. Logic dictates that both machines will do exactly the same thing

Comment: Also check that your global composer config on both machines doesn't have anything unusual in it

Comment: You say you checked the AMP stack versions, but did you check the CLI version of PHP too? `php -v`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Clive, we ended up completely wiping and restoring the laptop from a time machine backup of my (working) laptop. Although it seemed to solve the issue, this was a dissatisfying solution, since we still didn't know what the root cause was. However, I did some more digging and I discovered this on the Composer issues queue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7764 - It seems a stricter approach to resolving dependencies in Composer 1.7.3 was causing this issue. Rolling back to composer 1.7.2 allowed us to continue using the existing Composer.lock files again.